# Setting up Storyboard for performSegueWithIdentifier()

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I'm working on a page of my app where a user selects one of 3 cells from a UITableView and is taken to a corresponding 1 of 2 UIViewControllers that populates a page with details about the selected cell. I'm trying to prepare my storyboard to do this with 'performSegueWithIdentifier()'. I have made a segue by connecting the view controller of the parent view with the views of each child view using the 'show' method. I then added this to my parent view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        appDelegate.selected = 1
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GraphID", sender: self)
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        appDelegate.selected = 2
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DistanceID", sender: self)
    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        appDelegate.selected = 3
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GraphID", sender: self)
    }    
}
```

[image]

When I launch my app and press any cell it crashes with an NSException:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver     (<FlightTracker.StatusViewController: 0x7fe4faa5c8c0>) has no segue with identifier 'DistanceID''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109446f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001090dfbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   UIKit                               0x0000000109b9dd3b -[UIViewController     shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001174dec78 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility     performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 39
    4   FlightTracker                       0x0000000106f977e2  _TFC13FlightTracker20StatusViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCS o11NSIndexPath_T_ + 2530
    5   FlightTracker                       0x0000000106f97cef _TToFC13FlightTracker20StatusViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 79
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000109b5e393 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1293
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000109b5e4d4 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000109a99331 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000109a991ab _afterCACommitHandler + 516
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010937bdc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010937bd20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109371b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109371486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b1ba9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000109a76420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    16  FlightTracker                       0x0000000106fac07e top_level_code + 78
    17  FlightTracker                       0x0000000106fac0ba main + 42
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010bdc5145 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Have I connected my storyboard correctly to use this method?

Comment: If you're getting any error message, you need to post it in full.

Comment: That error message is quite clear. Your StatusViewController apparently doesn't have a segue called DistanceID. Either you have a spelling mistake, or you forgot to add the identifier in the storyboard. There are other possibilities, but you should check those first.

Comment: In the above screenshot I opened the UIViewController and the identifier can be read to be right. Thats why I was wondering if I had made the right segue? (That is from StatusViewController to my second view controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the photo you post, you are setting a StoryboardID call `DistanceID`. And this is quite different from `segue identifier` which we are talking about.

So, instead, choose the `segue` between viewControllers and change the identifier to `DistanceID`. That is the correct identifier.

Comment: Well it turns out that was the problem I was looking for. Thanks for pointing that out! Have a great night!